tauri - how can I configure multiple plugins + a normal server using vite?
Is it possible to configure Vite to support two types of plugs (e.g react + svelte) and have a normal web server all running on the same port?
Also, how would I go about including all the different directories (one for svelte files/react/normal html) so that they are built as part of cargo tauri build?
